# $R$ is the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-k}]$. In $R$, if $3\mid (a+b\sqrt{-k})$, then $3\mid a$ and $3\mid b$ in $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: ring-theory

$R$ is the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-k}]$ where $k\ge 5$ and $k\equiv2 \pmod{3}$.

I would like to prove that in $R$, if $3\mid(a+b\sqrt{-k})$, then $3\mid a$ and $3\mid b$ in $\mathbb{Z}$. I have proved the opposite direction, how can I prove this direction?

Also, I think $3$ is irreducible in $R$, is this correct and how can I prove that too?

Comment: Have you tried using the definition of divisibility? If $3\mid a+b\sqrt{-k}$, then there exists an element of $R$ such that ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The implication you're looking for is easy: if $a+b\sqrt{-k}=3(x+y\sqrt{-k})$, then
$$
a=3x,\qquad b=3y
$$
by equating the real and imaginary parts.

More interesting is asking whether $3$ is irreducible. Suppose
$$
(a+b\sqrt{-k})(c+d\sqrt{-k})=3
$$
with both elements in the left hand sides noninvertible. Then, by taking conjugates,
$$
(a^2+b^2k)(c^2+d^2k)=9
$$
so, since the elements are noninvertible, $a^2+b^2k=3$. Since $k\ge5$, this forces $b=0$.